# Group a set of chain values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table in SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @UnitConvert table 
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  ConvertUnitOne nvarchar(50),
  ConvertUnitTwo nvarchar(50)
) 


INSERT INTO @UnitConvert
SELECT 100,500
UNION ALL SELECT 200,100
UNION ALL SELECT 500,300
UNION ALL SELECT 2000,1000
UNION ALL SELECT 3000,9000
UNION ALL SELECT 2000,700
UNION ALL SELECT 820,3000

SELECT * FROM @UnitConvert
```

Here value in UnitConvertOne is equivalent to UnitConvertTwo
So it has a chain of value linking

So i want to display the result like

```
Group         unit

1             100

              200

              300

              500

2             700

              1000

              2000

3             820

              3000

              9000
```

Group value will be autoincrement based on the number of groups can be created
Unit value can be sorted from small to large value

Comment: I am unable to understand. How is UnitConvertOne equivalent to UnitConvertTwo? What is the logic for the output ?

Comment: we r inserting some dimension unit equivalent to some unit here we inserted
100 = 500,200=100,500=300..so 100,200,300,500 make a group

Comment: edited the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene Elutin from sqlservercentral.com

```
DECLARE @UnitConvert table 
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  ConvertUnitOne nvarchar(50),
  ConvertUnitTwo nvarchar(50)
) 

INSERT INTO @UnitConvert
SELECT 100,500
UNION ALL SELECT 200,100
UNION ALL SELECT 500,300
UNION ALL SELECT 2000,1000
UNION ALL SELECT 3000,9000
UNION ALL SELECT 2000,700
UNION ALL SELECT 820,3000

;WITH cteUP AS
(
 SELECT  ConvertUnitTwo AS childUP, ConvertUnitOne AS unitUP, 0 AS Lvl
 FROM @UnitConvert 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT cte.childUP, u.ConvertUnitOne AS unitUP, Lvl = Lvl + 1 
 FROM @UnitConvert u
 INNER  JOIN cteUP cte ON cte.unitUP = u.ConvertUnitTwo
)
--select * from cteUP
SELECT   c.ConvertUnit
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ISNULL(cm.unitUP, c.ConvertUnit)) AS GrpNO
FROM   (SELECT ConvertUnitOne AS ConvertUnit FROM @UnitConvert 
        UNION 
        SELECT ConvertUnitTwo AS ConvertUnit FROM @UnitConvert) c
OUTER APPLY (SELECT  TOP 1 unitUP FROM cteUP m WHERE
             m.childUP = c.ConvertUnit ORDER BY Lvl DESC) cm
```